# Performance Comparison - Mojo vs Python

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking, mojolang

Mojo, a programming language, claims to be 65000x faster than python. I am eager to understand if is there any concrete benchmark data that supports this claim? Also, how does it differ in real world problems?

I am primarily encountered this claim on their website and have watched several videos discussing Mojo's speed. However I am seeking concrete benchmark data that substantiates this assertion.

Comment: Mojo is compiled to machine code like C, Python interprets byte code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The claim directly comes from a [blog on the Mojo website](https://www.modular.com/blog/mojo-a-journey-to-68-000x-speedup-over-python-part-3). The benchmark is a computation of the Mandelbrot set. It is **not a rigorous benchmark nor one representative of most Python applications**. It is also clearly **biased** (e.g. sequential VS parallel codes).

They choose it because it has the following properties: "Simple to express", "Pure compute" (ie. compute-bound), "Irregular computation", "Embarrassingly parallel", "Vectorizable". They also states "Mandelbrot is a nice problem that demonstrates the capabilities of Mojo". This is the kind of problem where Python does not shine (and it not meant to be used for), but on which Mojo shine well (pretty optimal use-case for it). Thus, the speed-up can be pretty huge. In fact, this benchmark is rather a maximum speed-up you can get and not an average of many real-world applications.

First things first, it means nothing to compare language performance. We compare **implementations**. CPython is the standard Python implementation, but not the only one. CPython is an **interpreter** so a code is very slow when a it is fully interpreted. Optimized Python codes tends not to run much interpreted code but *vectorized* ones (eg. the script mostly calls Numpy optimized functions written in C).

PyPy is an alternative implementation which uses a **JIT-compiler** to run code faster. It [claims 4.8x faster performance compared to CPython](https://speed.pypy.org/) with a detailed set of benchmarks (geometric average). There are some benchmark that are very hard to make faster, even using a native language. Symbolic and large string computations are hard to make faster (CPython string are already well optimized in C). It tends to be faster for numerical codes.

In the Mojo benchmark, the naive Python codes, Numpy ones and PyPy ones are **sequential** while the final Mojo code is multi-threaded. This is **not a fair comparison**. One should have to use at least the *multiprocessing* module to compare parallel codes together. This is a critical point since they run the code on a **88-Core Intel Xeon** CPU. Indeed, since the computation is compute-bound, one can expect a speed up close to 88 using multiple threads. In fact, their parallel Mojo implementation is 85 times faster than their sequential Mojo one. Without a parallel Python implementation, It would be more fair to claim that Mojo is 874 times faster than a naive CPython implementation, 175 times faster than a (rather naive) Numpy code, and 40 times faster than a PyPy implementation (on this specific Mandelbrot set computation).

In sequential, most of the speed-up comes from the use of [**SIMD**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction_multiple_data) instructions and [instruction-level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism). The Python implementations tends not to use them. While Numpy can do that, not all functions are well vectorized (the one operating on Complex numbers tends not to be AFAIK) and Numpy codes tends to be memory-bound due to the creation of many large temporary arrays.

Note that tools like **Numba and Cython** are not shown in the benchmark while they are frequently used to speed up numerical codes. It would be more fair to add them (or at least mention them).

Comment: Thank you very much for your Explanation and reference article. In short, its clear that Mojo is fast but exact number that how much it is faster, it depends on implementation. So direct comparison of languages doesn't make sense until we consider implementations. Right?

Comment: The key to huge speedups: pick a good language that can compile to efficient parallel code.  Then pick the worst possible thing to compare it against. :P  Like a serial fully naive function (e.g. using `abs()` which includes a square root) manually looping for each pixel separately in slow interpreter like CPython where that's the worst thing you can do.  (Interpreter overhead is so high that it might be faster to do 100 iterations for an array of pixels before checking if they've all escaped, esp. with NumPy.  Or just not use a super-slow interpreter if you want performance.)

Comment: @Developer: Yeah, especially for Python where there's huge variation in the implementations. The de-facto standard implementation is still CPython, the slow interpreter.  In some other languages, for example C++, the only mainstream implementations are optimizing compilers that do an ok job most of the time, a good job some of the time.  But at worst for simple loops make asm that works pretty much like the source, if the source didn't vectorize or parallelize.  (Well, at *worst* they can vectorize so badly that it's worse than scalar, or unexpectedly do something slow...)